# yii cgridview input text and select filter is disabled

Tags: php, filtering, yii, cgridview

[EDIT]
There are just some js code that I used for sorting that disables the selection the div container.

I am using the Yii cgridview to show my data. But I cannot type into the input text field and cannot select from the select/dropdown, these are the filter options on the cgridview. By the way, the data is from a view, not a from a regular table.

Below are codes on my controller,

```
$request = new Request;
$request->unsetAttributes();

if(isset($_GET['Request'])
 $request->attributes=$_GET['Request'];

$this->render('index', array(
            'request' => $request,
        ));
```

Below are the safe fields on the model,

```
array('request_id, facility_id, client_id, status, description, submitted_by, submitted, acknowledge, req_type', 'safe')
```

Below are the codes on the model search method

```
function setRequests(){

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('req_type',$this->req_type, true);
$criteria->compare('description', $this->description, true);
$criteria->compare('status', $this->status, true);

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
         'criteria' => $criteria,
          'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>5),
        ));
}
```

Below are the codes on the view file.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'request-clist',
            'dataProvider'=>$request->setRequests(),
            'filter'=>$request,
            'columns'=>
            array(
                    array('name'=>'req_type', 
                        'header'=>'Item',
                        'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->req_type, array($data->url));',
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'filter' => CHtml::dropDownList('Request[req_type]',
                        $request->req_type, 
                        array(
                            'Notice' => 'Notice',
                            'FAR' => 'FAR', 
                            'PC' => 'PC',
                            'EM'=>'EM',
                            'RH'=>'RH'),
                        array('empty' => '(Select)'))
                        ),
                    array('name'=>'description', 
                        'header'=>'Description',
                        'filter'=>CHtml::textField('Request[description]',$request->description)),
                    array('name'=>'status',
                         'header'=>'Status',
                         'filter'=>CHtml::textField('Request[status]',$request->status)),
            ),
    ));
```

Are there some things I miss?

Comment: array('request_id, facility_id, client_id, status, description, submitted_by, submitted, acknowledge, req_type', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'); // Add 'on'=>'search' for attributes to filter

Comment: @DanielVaquero tried adding 'on'=>'search' but still not working

Comment: comment 'filter'=>$request, on CGridView. Use the setRequests() filter.

Comment: @DanielVaquero thanks, same problem. i can see the filter, problem is i cannot select or type into the filter fields.

Comment: I've never used filtering, where I manually create the dropdown and textfields as you're doing.  Just to see if it works, try not setting a value for "filter" in each column; except for the select box, where you'll provide an array of html options.